# PageView com PageController no Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Por favor, alguém me diz porque os botões que deveriam passar as telas não estão funcionado direito. Testei em um emulador android e em um celular android e nada de passar corretamente a view.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'PageViewController.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter PageView Demonstratio',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: HomeWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class HomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeWidgetState createState() => _HomeWidgetState();
}

class _HomeWidgetState extends State<HomeWidget> {
  PageController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> pages = ["BATATA", "CENOURA", "MAGERICÃO"];
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left),
              onPressed: () {
                controller.previousPage(
                    curve: Curves.easeInOutBack,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
              },
            ),

          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              onPressed: () {
                controller.jumpToPage(0);
              },
            ),

            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
              onPressed: () {
                controller.nextPage(
                    curve: Curves.easeInOutBack,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
              },
            ),
          ],
          title: Text("Page View"),
        ),
        body: PageView.builder(
          controller: controller,
          itemCount: pages.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            print(index);
            return Center(child: Text(pages[index]));
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Agora que vi desculpe, removi minhas resposta porque é mais simples que eu vi, faz o seguinte troca a animicao do curves para ease, por algum motivo q ainda nao descobri com essa animacao easeInOutBack ele nao  avanca.

Comment: Sim, era isso mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, mano!

Comment: Deve ser um bug do Flutter ou sei lá

Comment: mas é interessante vc botar como resposta para eu poder fechar a pegunta

Comment: Você mesmo deve reponder a perguntar, foi algo muito simples. Só coloca o que era o problema e pronto respondido

Comment: @JustCase No caso o Marcos estava certo... Você  achou a solução, então seria interessante você montar um resposta mostrando onde é pra ser feita a mudança dando uma breve explicação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O @JustCase solucionou o problema:

> faz o seguinte troca a animação do curves para ease, por algum motivo q ainda nao descobri com essa animação easeInOutBack ele nao avanca

ainda não sabemos por que a animação easeInOutBack não funcionou.